# Использование UDID на не оплаченном аккаунте

Tags: xcode

Опишу суть проблемы: несколько лет назад покупал аккаунт apple developer, устанавливал приложение на разные телефоны, добавлял в store приложения... На данный момент аккаунт не оплачен, но вполне рабочий (видны приложения, добавленные в itunesconnect). Но новый UDID устройства добавить не получается. 
Вопрос: Можно ли будет установить приложение через xcode (через кабель) на устройство, UDID которого не добавлен в мой сертификат? И как поведет себя xcode в этом случае - имеется ввиду что теперь (в версии 8) автоматически происходят всякие махинации с сертификатами, добавится ли UDID таким образом в мой сертификат ?

Comment: Нет, нельзя, проверил.

Comment: начиная с xcode то ли 6 то ли 7, вам нужен оплаченый аккаунт только чтоб загружать в аппстор. все остальное должно работать